# Training an LSTM on two merged writing styles (say Shakespeare and Frost)

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm, text-generation

I was trying to develop intuitions on how two writing styles can be merged (if at all they can be merged) into a single LSTM and then get meaningful results from the same.

Can anybody provide me with some insights on how to go about this? I wish to see if I can go about merging Shakespeare and Frost into one model and then get the generated text be like ***picking up nature themes from Frost and mixing in them a flavour of Shakespeare***?

How do you all feel about this?